# Prefix or Append HTML file using Python

Tags: python-3.x, append, smtplib

I am trying to send multiple emails using smtplib in python. I am reading the email body from a html file. And i am able to use the html file in the email body to send emails. However, i need to prefix the recipients name (from a csv, running in loop) to the email body (html).

```
appendfile  = open('EmailFormatv3.html','a')    

appendMe.write(new_format.html)
new_format.write(appendfile)

appendfile.close()
```

I tried append, but that may not be the correct way for doing it. Please advise the best way to add send name to email body. Thank you

Comment: Are you trying to read from an html file, and use that as your email body you intend to send to other users?

Comment: Yes i am reading the html file as email body. Now, need to prefix recipient name to the body

Comment: All you need to do is declare the sender's email address in a variable, and use that variable in the `smtp.sendmail` parameters. There's plenty of examples out there, here's one: [link](http://gaurprashant.blogspot.com/2013/09/send-fake-email-using-python-smtp.html)